# Traverse Angular cache factory

Tags: angularjs

To retrieve an element from [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) you use `cache.get('key1')`, but how to traverse the list and obtain all the key/values?

Comment: Do you try cache.info()

Comment: it only returns the name and the size

Comment: You can't do it directly. However, it's quite easy to decorate existing cache instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I speak too fast, sorry...

In fact, it seems that it is not possible to do it. I searched into angular source code and cache is just a dummy JS Object. It is not accessible and no method allow you to access it directly.

Here is the code from the lastest angular version : [$cacheFactory](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b9bed7d9dadb4ba1a4186f2ae562f807b21bcf12/src/ng/cacheFactory.js)

Comment: Of course it will not work, because cache.info is not a collection.

Comment: I know, the problem is that `cache.info` is a function and although it's while also an object, it doesn't store individual entries keys. So `forEach` will not do anything. Just try it your self.